# UK and Schengen visa fund question from India

Tags: visas, schengen, uk

We are applying for UK and Schengen visas consecutively as that seems to be the requirement, though it is one combined visit for us. We plan to arrive in Europe and then go across to UK and head back to India from there. The funding for this visit is from savings. My question is, do we need to have funds in the bank for the Europe and UK visit at the time of applying for UK visa, or is it enough if we have enough for UK at time of applying for that, and liquidate more savings at time of applying for Schengen?

Comment: It's better if you identify which Schengen consulate you want to apply to AND if you will apply for both before leaving India or apply for the Schengen from the UK or vice-versa.

Comment: Applying to France before we leave, since that will be our entry pt and longest period of stay. Have to liquidate savings, so wanted to know if I can wait for till UK visa comes before liquidating enough for both countries, or smarter to have the full amt in the bank - and statement - for the UK visa application itself.

Answer (score 2):

It does not make any difference at application time.

However when you arrive in either the UK or France you may undergo an inspection of your documents.  If a recent bank statement shows a large influx of cash and it does not sync up with the stuff you submitted as evidence, they will get *worried*.  So logistically you are better off getting your cash sorted out all at once, especially if Schengen and the UK are part of a single journey.

Comment: Well, we are liquidating savings for this, so there will be a couple of large inflows - bonafide sale of stocks and deposits, etc. So if I explain that in the covering letter or the additional information, will that be enough? And yes, you seconded my gut feel that it is better to have it all in together.

Comment: @Radhika  No, it's not enough. Decidedly not.  This changes the semantics of your question, please edit, or ask a new question.  http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1737+provenance